# JavaCV recorder записывает не все фреймы

Tags: java, видео, ffmpeg, javacv

Получаю видео с rtsp потока и записываю его в файл. Длительность видео должно быть равно одной минуте

```
double partFrame = grabber.getFrameRate() * 60;
            while (running && grabber != null && (frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {                    
                recorder.record(frame);                    
                if (++frames == partFrame) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder = nextFrameRecorder(grabber.getImageWidth(), grabber.getImageHeight());
                    frames = 0;
                    recorder.start();
                }                    
            }
```

самому рекордеру задаю такие параметры

```
    recorder.setVideoCodec(28);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P);
    recorder.setFrameRate(grabber.getFrameRate());
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(grabber.getVideoBitrate());
```

На выходе получаю видео 58 секунд. В чем проблема?

Comment: flush для рекордера делали? В силу особенностей энкодеров, они не сразу рождают пакеты на выходе. Поэтому после вашего основного цикла нужно покормить рекордер нулевыми фреймами до тех пор, пока не будет получена ошибка или какой-то другой статус. Это же у вас JavaCV? Какой версии? Ну и плюс - можете выложить получившийся фрагмент (на 58 сек) в сеть, для анализа?

Comment: Использую JavaCV 0.10. Видео [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/KD9-L0lyjurc9)

Answer (score 1):

Да, проанализировав ваш файл, действительно там 1452 фрейма, что при FPS 25 составляет 58.08 сек видео.

Собственно, посмотрев в реализацию FFmpegFrameRecorder::record() я вижу, что ситуацию с null-фреймом он обрабатывает. С одним но... Там в FFmpegFrameRecorder::record(IplImage image, int pixelFormat) баг: для первого пропихнутого null-фрейма, если он не ключевой, вернётся false и очередь кодоровщика не будет опустошена. В 1.0 этот баг исправлен.

Если есть возможность сменить версию - смените. Если нет, но есть возможность пересобрать из исходников, то исправьте такой возврат (строка 735):

```
return (video_pkt.flags() & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY) == 1;
```

на что-то вроде (код из 1.0):

```
return image != null ? (video_pkt.flags() & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY) != 0 : got_video_packet[0] != 0;
```

в противном случае, я не вижу возможности узнать, что очередь кодировщика опустошена.

Ваш же код менять не нужно. Сброс очереди происходит в методе stop().

Comment: в JavaCV 0.10 grabber.grab() возвращал мне IplImage. В версии 1.0 возвращается Frame.  Изменил библиотеку на 1,0. Теперь видео длится 49 секунт [ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/PORYeALKjv9mr)

Comment: Сейчас решил останавливать видео не по количеству видео, а по таймеру. Просто переставать писать в файл раз в минуту и начинать писать в другой. Видео получаются ровно по 1 минуте

Comment: Один косяк исправили, другой добавили. Нормально. Вы, кстати, нигде не делаете setInterleaved(false)?

Comment: еще проблема есть такая. Если я обрываю соединение с интернетом, то у меня висит на этом условии
`while (running && grabber != null && (frame = grabber.grab()) != null)`
Причем это зависит от потока. На одном потоке выходит из цикла, а в другом висит как я понял в методе frame = grabber.grab()

Comment: в C API FFmpeg для этого есть т.н. AVIO Interrupt Handler - пользовательская функция которая вызывается в потенциально долгих местах, и по возвращаемому значению - или прерывается или идёт на следующую попытку. Тут даже не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

изменил условие подсчетов фреймов на

```
                if (!frame.keyFrame)
                    frames++;
                if (frames == partFrame) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    ..........
                }
```

Теперь видео ровно столько сколько мне и надо. Спасибо Monah Tuk, очень помог мне!

Comment: Решение не совсем корректное: вы считаете только неключевые кадры, то сейчас сработало - может потом боком выйти. Вообще имеет смысл создать тикет разработчику с минимальным примером где проблема воспроизводится - пусть разбирается. Я сам не Java кодер, но с точки зрения FFmpeg процесс неплохо знаю: раз фреймов не хватает, значит они не вытолкнулись, значит плохо flush сделан. Ещё интересно как там timestamp считаются и пересчитываются.

Comment: Да, ещё у вас при таком подходе будут теряться кадры. Можете проверить, взять на вход какой-то файл с известным количеством кадров, в результирующих получится в сумме меньше и дырка на стыке.

Comment: Еще мне надо вставлять текущую дату в кадр. Вы советовали использовать `FrameFilter`, но в библиотеки `JavaCV 1.0` его тоже нет. беру тут [JavaCV](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacv/1.0). Поэтому с помощью `Java2DFrameConverter` получаю из фрейма `BufferedImage`. Так вот. Не из каждого фрейма можно получить `BufferedImage`. Выпадает ошибка `nullPointerException`. Пришлось добавить тоже самое условие 
`if (!frame.keyFrame) {
     image = frameConverter.convert(frame);`

Comment: Скорее всего появилось в master барнче в git. Возможно фейлы на тех фреймах, которые содержат аудио-данные. Можете попытаться завести отдельный вопрос для этого.